# Need Parent Buttons Outside iFrame to Call JS Functions Loaded Inside the iFrame

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

This is a weird question and I hate iFrames, but I am using PhoneGap and Codiqa for mobile application development and Codiqa outputs HTML and for all the outside forms I want to incorporate within Codiqa's HTML it loads in iframes. Codiqa uses div ID referencing so that when you click a menu item, it loads that page ID in the HTML and then also in the parent window loads the iframe inside that div. Also, the parent window has its own submit, reset, and back buttons. I need those buttons to call to and use functions from the page that loads WITHIN the iFrame...

Apparently, this is the exact opposite of how parent.myfunction() works, and I wonder if this is even possible or if I need to just recreate my code and not use iFrames, but I am clueless as to how I can go about that. PHP includes don't really work well I have come to find out... Thanks! Or maybe I just need to move all my JS files for each form into parent folders and have to link to the forms separately? I don't know... Please advise. Here is an example of one of the page IDs:

HTML (Codiqa)

```
<a href="#page17" data-transition="flip">
   Extracting
</a>

<div data-role="page" id="page17">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>Extracting</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <iframe src="extraction/extract_form.html"
            name="Cable_Extraction_Worksheet" class="contentiframe"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div data-role="tabbar" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="a">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page1" data-transition="flip" data-theme="" data-icon="arrow-l">
                  Back
              </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-transition="none" data-theme="" data-icon="minus">
                  Reset
              </a>
                </li>
                <li>//THIS IS THE BUTTON, AND JS FUNCTION I NEED TO CALL ONCLICK
                    <a onclick="uploaddata();" data-transition="none" data-theme="" data-icon="check">
                  Submit
              </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

IFRAME'S JS FUNCTION

```
function uploaddata() { 

//Read all of the data from the page
for (eID in extractform) {
    extractform[eID] = document.getElementById(eID).value;
}
        upload_extractform();
}
function upload_extractform() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './php/upload_extractform.php',
    data: extractform,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function() {
        alert("Thank you. Your Extraction form has been submitted.");

},

        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error... " + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    }
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what I am looking for:

onclick="document.getElementById('Cable_Extraction_Worksheet').contentWindow.uploaddata();"

is this reliable?? Some say it doesn't work in all browsers or with a function that has Jquery in it, which some of mine do. Just want to verify, thanks.

Comment: Also, I need to be able to actually use the iFrame's form action, method, and onsubmit functions form the parent onclick event... How can I do this?